# implement rfind in Python

Tags: python, string, methods

I am attempting to implement the `rfind` function in Python without using the built-in `rfind` method. It should work like the following:
Unlike the original method, takes an input string and a character as a parameter and returns the first index from the right where the character is found. Now I am getting stuck on what to do next..

```
# main function
inputString = input("Enter here: ")
inputChar = input("Which character would you like to find?")
print(Myrfind(inputString, inputChar))

def Myrfind(text,aChar):
    reverseString = text[::-1]
    for ch in reverseString:
        if ch == aChar:
            print()
        else:
            return -1
```

Comment: why do you use `print()` instead of `return` ?

Comment: @furas he wants to see the value of the variable, maybe? Yet maybe there's `return` missing _after_ the print function.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach, IMHO, would be to just iterate over the string backwards and compare each character:

```
def myrfind(text, aChar):
    for i in range(len(text) - 1, -1, -1):
        if text[i]  == aChar:
            return i
    return -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be like (with minimal changes in current code):

```
def Myrfind(text,aChar):
    reverseString = text[::-1]
    for i, c in enumerate(reverseString):  # enumerate() to iterate along with index
        if c == aChar:
            return len(text) - i - 1  # Return len(char) - i -1 since reverse string
    else:          # Return -1 if function is not
        return -1  # exited by for loop
```

Sample run:

```
>>> Myrfind('Hello', 'o')
4
>>> Myrfind('Hello', 'l')
3
>>> Myrfind('Hello', 'e')
1
>>> Myrfind('Hello', 'a')  # 'a' not in string
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in `ch` you have the *character*, not the *index of the character*, so even if you find it, you won't be able to know its index (you just know that the character is in your `text` string, nothing else)

Also, when you find a coincidence, you print... nothing (in `print()`)

And since the `return -1` (when not found) is within the `for` loop, you will stop the execution (returning `-1`) as soon as a character doesn't match the looked up character (you should be very familiar with the [return](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/returnst.htm) statement)

You reverse the string, but that is probably not very... "adviseable", because then your indexes get reversed. For instance, let's say you want to find the last `l` in `Hello`. You are expecting:

```
       H e l l o
Index  0 1 2 3 4
```

And that should be `3`, but since you reverse it, and start walking it from left to right, you get:

```
       o l l e H
Index  0 1 2 3 4
```

And the first match is in `1`, now... You can still do it, though... You can substract that index to the total lenght, and you should get it.

Firstly, I would recommend you read what the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in does (to not only get the character, but also the index)

A pretty close thing to what you have could be:

```
inputString = input("Enter here: ")
inputChar = input("Which character would you like to find?")


def Myrfind(text,aChar):
    reverseString = text[::-1]
    for i, ch in enumerate(reverseString):
        if ch == aChar:
            return len(text) - 1 - i
    return -1


print(Myrfind(inputString, inputChar))
```

Or, instead of inverting the array, just start reading from the right (see what [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) does)

```
def Myrfind(text,aChar):
    for i in range(len(text) - 1, -1, -1):
        ch = text[i]
        if ch == aChar:
            return i
    return -1
```